# How to use MergeSort to sort pickle objects based on an attribute?

Tags: python, pickle, mergesort

I am creating a database program, and I am trying to incorporate a sorting system. I have multiple objects, which are all `Students`. These students have three attributes: `name`, `grade`, and `average`.

I am trying to make the program sort through the averages of the students, and then display the students in order of highest to lowest average. I have been able to unpick the external file where the objects are stored, and then store the averages of each student into a list. Once I have the list, I can use MergeSort to sort the list. However, I cannot figure out how to use the sorted list to sort and display each object. I've tried to use search to find where an average is located in the object list, so then I can display that object, but I cannot get it to work correctly.

My program is as follows:

```
import pickle

class Student():
    def __init__(self,nam,grd,avg):
        self.name = nam
        self.grade = grd
        self.average = avg

    def get_details(self):
        print(self.name, self.grade, self.average)

    def create_item():
        new_student = Student(input("Enter name: "),input("Enter grade: "), input("Enter average: "))
        save_object(new_student, 'student_data.pkl')

def clear_database():
    file = open('student_data.pkl', 'w')
    file.close()

def save_object(obj, filename):
    with open(filename, 'ab') as output:
        pickle.dump(obj, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def unpickle_database(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                break

def display_database():
    print("\nName:               Grade:              Average:            ")
    for student in unpickle_database('student_data.pkl'):
        property_list = [student.name, student.grade, student.average]
        print(''.join([v.ljust(20,' ') for v in property_list]))

def delete_student(student_to_delete, filename):
    students = list(unpickle_database(filename))
    del students[student_to_delete-1]
    clear_database()
    for student in students:
        save_object(student, filename)

def store_grades_in_list():
    students = list(unpickle_database('student_data.pkl'))
    students_grade = []
    for student in students:
        students_grade.append(int(student.grade))
    return students_grade

def store_averages_in_list():
    students = list(unpickle_database('student_data.pkl'))
    students_average = []
    for student in students:
        students_average.append(int(student.average))
    return students_average

def merge(st1, st2, st3):
    i1 = i2 = i3 = 0
    n1, n2 = len(st1), len(st2)

    while i1 < n1 and i2 < n2:
        if st1[i1] < st2[i2]:
            st3[i3] = st1[i1]
            i1 = i1 + 1
        else:
            st3[i3] = st2[i2]
            i2 = i2 + 1
        i3 = i3 + 1

    while i1 < len(st1):
        st3[i3] = st1[i1]
        i1 = i1 + 1
        i3 = i3 + 1

    while i2 < len(st2):
        st3[i3] = st2[i2]
        i2 = i2 + 1
        i3 = i3 + 1

def mergeSort(st):
    n = len(st)
    if n > 1:
        m = n//2
        st1, st2 = st[:m], st[m:]
        mergeSort(st1)
        mergeSort(st2)
        merge(st1, st2, st)
    return st

def bin_search(x):
    my_list = store_averages_in_list()
    bottom = 0
    top = len(my_list)-1
    found = False
    location = -1
    while (bottom <= top) and not(found):
        middle = int((bottom + top)/2)

        if (my_list[middle] == x):
            location = middle
            found = True
        elif (my_list[middle] < x):
            bottom = middle + 1
        else:
            top = middle -1
    return location

while True:
    user_input = input("\nType \"Clear\" to clear the database. Type \"Add\" to add a student. Type \"Display\" to display the database contents. Type \"Quit\" to quit the program. Type \"Remove\" to remove a student. Type \"Search\" to serach for an average. Type \"Sort av\" to display sorted list of averages.\n")
    if user_input == "Quit":
        break
    elif user_input == "Clear":
        clear_database()
        print("\nThe database has been cleared.")
    elif user_input == "Add":
        Student.create_item()
        print("\nThe student has been added. The updated database is: ")
        display_database()
    elif user_input == "Display":
        display_database()
    elif user_input == "Remove":
        student_to_delete = int(input("Type the student number that you would like to delete: "))
        delete_student(student_to_delete,'student_data.pkl')
        print("\nThe student has been deleted. The updated database is: ")
        display_database()
    elif user_input == "Display Characteristics":
        store_chars_in_list()
    elif user_input == "Sort av":
        print(mergeSort(store_averages_in_list()))
    elif user_input == "Sort gr":
        print(mergeSort(store_grades_in_list()))
    elif user_input == "Search":
        print(bin_search(int(input("Enter average to search for: "))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's two things you need to do to accomplish this.

1. Instead of passing a list of the students *averages* into the mergesort function(s), you need to pass in a list of the `Student` objects themselves.
2. The `mergesort` function won't change, but the `merge` function will.  Since the elements in the list are no longer numbers, but `Student` objects, instead of comparing `st1[i1] < st2[i2]` or similar, you'll need to compare something like `st1[i1].average < st2[i2].average` or the like.  That way, you're not sorting a list of *averages*, but a list of `Student`s.  Then, once you have a sorted list of students, you can display it however you like.

This answer intentionally has as little explicit code as possible, because this question feels like it's assigned as a school assignment, and it will behoove you to take the information I've given and play with it :)

Side note: if you're just looking to sort a list of `Student`s and don't need or want to write mergesort yourself, the following code will work:

```
students = ... # list of Student
sorted_students = list(sorted(students, key=attrgetter('average'))
```

using the `attrgetter` function from the `operator` library.

Comment: Thanks for your information! I have been experimenting with using the sorted() function, however it isn't correctly sorting the data when there are varying numbers of digits. I have sorted_students = list(sorted(store_students_in_list(), key=attrgetter('average'), reverse=False)). When the averages are: 57, 89, 100, 68, 77; they become sorted like: 100, 57, 68, 77, 89. This isn't right, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: It sounds like `average` is a string rather than a number, and strings get sorted lexicographically (alphabetically).  To fix this, you'll need to convert the averages from strings to numbers.  One example of how to do this would be `list(sorted(key=(lambda d: float(d.average)), ...))`.

This won't modify the actual `average` attribute on the students, but rather will just use a smarter comparison function to order them correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've got it working now! I figured it was something like that, but I wasn't quite sure how to fix the problem.